# Windows Server 2008 R2 Environment Variables

Tags: environment-variables, windows-server-2008-r2

How do you set environment variables on Windows Server 2008 R2, specifically the PATH variable? The Microsoft Help source provides advice that doesn't match the screens and options I see on my server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Server Manager console home page, you can click on Change System Properties on the right side.
[image: Server 2008]

Then click on the Advanced Tab, and the Environment Variables button...
[image]